# Write a program the compress the string

Tags: java, string, algorithm

Question:
Run-length encoding (RLE) is a simple "compression algorithm" (an algorithm which takes a block of data and reduces its size, producing a block that contains the same information in less space). It works by replacing repetitive sequences of identical data items with short "tokens" that represent entire sequences. Applying RLE to a string involves finding sequences in the string where the same character repeats. Each such sequence should be replaced by a "token" consisting of:

```
the number of characters in the sequence
the repeating character
```

If a character does not repeat, it should be left alone.

For example, consider the following string:

```
qwwwwwwwwweeeeerrtyyyyyqqqqwEErTTT
```

After applying the RLE algorithm, this string is converted into:

```
q9w5e2rt5y4qw2Er3T
```

This is what I have so far, I don't know how to count the characters like how many times a character is repeated. Can someone please help!!!!

```
public class Compress1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        String input = IO.readString();
        char[] inputChar = input.toCharArray();
        for (int index = 0; index < inputChar.length; index++){
            char current = inputChar[index];

            if (current == (current + 1)){
                int count = 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
String str = "qwwwwwwwwweeeeerrtyyyyyqqqqwEErTTT";
char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
int count = 1;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char prev = arr[0];

for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    char curr = arr[i];
    prev = arr[i - 1];
    if (curr == prev) {
        count++;
    } else {
        if (count < 2) {
            sb.append(prev);
        } else {
            sb.append(count).append(prev);
            count = 1;
        }
    }
}

if (count < 2) {
    sb.append(prev);
} else {
    sb.append(count).append(prev);
}

System.out.println("Compressed : " + sb.toString());
```

output : `Compressed : q9w5e2rt5y4qw2Er3T`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than debug your code, here's some working code:

```
String input = "qwwwwwwwwweeeeerrtyyyyyqqqqwEErTTT";

String previous = input.substring(0, 1);
int count = 1;
for (String c : input.substring(1).split("")) {
    if (previous.equals(c)) {
        count++;
    } else {
        System.out.print((count == 1 ? "" : count) + previous);
        previous = c;
        count = 1;
    }
}
System.out.println((count == 1 ? "" : count) + previous);
```

**Output:**

```
q9w5e2rt5y4qw2Er3T
```

Compare it with your own and follow its logic to find out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of your code.  It walks along an input string character by character.  If the next character be *different* than the preceding one, then it prints RLE version of the character (i.e. just the character if it occurred only once, or a number followed by the character in case it occurred more than once).  If the next character be the *same* as the preceding one, then it increments a counter to keep track of the number of occurrences.

If you look closely, you will notice that I append a new line (`\n`) to the end of the input string.  This allows my algorithm to "know" that it has hit the end of the input string.  And it also will nicely print a newline in the event that you plan to input multiple strings for RLE processing.

At some point, you may want to extract out a method which does the RLE processing.  For now, I have left the code as is inside your `main()` method.

```
public class Compress1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        String input = IO.readString();

        // check for null or empty input
        if (input == null || input.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println("null or empty string input");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // handle single character input
        if (input.length() == 1) {
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(curr));
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // add a newline character to the end of the input string
        // so the algorithm can detect a "change" at the end
        input += "\n";

        char curr = input.charAt(0);
        int count=1;

        for (int i=1; i < input.length(); ++i) {
            char next = input.charAt(i);
            if (curr != next) {
                if (count > 1) {
                    System.out.print(count + String.valueOf(curr));
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(curr);
                }
                count = 1;
            }
            else {
                ++count;
            }

            curr = next;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a sample input and output which I tested using IntelliJ:

**Input:**

```
qwwwwwwwwweeeeerrtyyyyyqqqqwEErTTT
```

**Output:**

```
q9w5e2rt5y4qw2Er3T
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    String input = IO.readString();
    final char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();
    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int index = 1;
    for (int current = 1, previous = 0; current <= charArray.length; current++, previous++) {
        if (current == charArray.length || charArray[previous] != charArray[current]) {
            if (index > 1) {
                stringBuilder.append(index);
            }
            stringBuilder.append(charArray[previous]);
            index = 1;
        } else {
            index++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
}
```